# It it possible to leverage type-checking to enforce a page endpoint's body returns required props?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

Consider the following page and page endpoint:

**routes/foo.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
  export let bar: string;
</script>

...
```

**routes/foo.ts**

```
export type Props = { bar: string };

export const get: RequestHandler<{}, Props> = () => {
   return {};
}
```

Even though `bar` is a required prop on the component, the endpoint can return without `body` being defined. Consequently, required props aren't supplied to the component. Is it possible to have typescript enforce that a body be returned with the expected type?

Furthermore, is it possible to define a component's props such that they formally conform to the `Props` interface?

Comment: For the most part, yes. Thanks!